# How to get an Id of a widget in GXT

Tags: gxt

here I got a problem with the setId of a window at the time of getId in order to retrieve the window name in  a loop. Here is a snippet:

```
int counter1 =1;
final Integer counter = new Integer(counter1);
windowDoneTextButton.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
                    if (counter <= 100) {
                    window.setId(new Integer(counter).toString());
                    windowQuestionVerticalLayoutContainer.setId(new Integer(counter).toString());
              window.hide();
              addItemSplitButton.removeFromParent();
              Label questionTitleLabelOfWindowQuestionTextField = new Label();
              questionTitleLabelOfWindowQuestionTextField.setText(windowQuestionTextField.getValue());
              Label questionHelpTextLabelOfWindowQuestionHelpTextTextField = new Label();
              questionHelpTextLabelOfWindowQuestionHelpTextTextField.setText(windowQuestionHelpTextTextField.getValue());
              FormPanel editFormPanel = new  FormPanel();
              HorizontalPanel editHorizontalPanel =  new HorizontalPanel();
              TextButton editButton  =  new TextButton();
             editButton.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
                  @Override
                    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
                      addItemSplitButton.removeFromParent();
                      window.show();
                      homePageVerticalLayoutContainer.add(window);
                homePageVerticalLayoutContainer.add(addItemSplitButton);
                  }
              });
```

Comment: whether setID is used for selinium testing

Comment: I don't know. What actually my idea is "whether can I refer an  Id for a widget for further modifications todo with the help of getId?"

Comment: Usually we used to set ensureDebugId or setID for QA team to do testing using selinum or QTP to identify an component.

Comment: So, what is the solution for my requirement?

Comment: for setId method ur passing same string.so it will show u same Id.So u need to differentiate id's while setting

Comment: K.But I want to remove the verticallayoutcontainer of that particular id. Because in my app I have to  add number of containers, I have differentiate them and edit again if I want. So how can I?

Comment: the string which is passing to SetId must be different as some panelname+count like that